# Three questions about Properties of Ext functor.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

I have three questions about the Ext functor's properties.

(i) $Ext(H \oplus H',G) = Ext(H,G) \oplus Ext(H',G)$

(ii) $Ext(H,G) = 0$ if $H$ is free

(iii) $Ext(\mathbb{Z_n}, G) = G/nG$

There is a short proof in Hatcher page 195 and here are my questions:

(i) For (i), it is say this is done ("clearly") by the free resolutions

$0 \to F_2 \to F_1 \to F_0 \to H \to 0$

$\oplus$

$0 \to F_2' \to F_1' \to F_0' \to H' \to 0$

= $0 \to F_2 \oplus F_2' \to F_1 \oplus F_1' \to F_0 \oplus F_0' \to H\oplus H' \to 0$

Can someone write down the detail in this? I feel like we can't just write what I did, take the Ext and compare it to the Ext when we direct sum.

(ii) The proof is $0 \to H \to H \to 0$. I am guessing this is because the Ext functor is invariant under $H$, so the $F_2 \to F_1 \to F_0 \to \dots$ doesn't matter and we can take all of that as just $H$ since $H$ is free. Unrelated, but how does the Ext functor depend/invariant on $G$?

(iii)

The proof is the map which is a dual of $0 \to Z \to Z \to Z_n \to 0$[image]

How do we get $Hom \to Ext$, the far left map? (Do not use vertical map)

Comment: (i) you are just taking direct sums of everything. (ii) $F_i=0$ for al $i>0$. (iii) this is the connecting map in the long exact sequence, and fact that $\text{Ext}(\Bbb Z,G)=0$.

Comment: (i) Yeah I find what I wrote is still not very rigorous. (ii) Oh right so the whole free resolution is free, so the maps $F_0 \to H$ is an inclusion and so the 1st cohomology group is also $0$ as the rest of the left maps (iii) You mind referencing the commutative diagram in the book...? I can't recall which it is.

Comment: Your statements are a bit confusing. You change $H$s to $A$ and $B$, and also probably mean $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ in the last bullet point, and not $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff thank you. I just changed it.